# Regex: extract multiple URL strings from a cell of arrays

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract, google-sheets-formula, string-matching

What is a clean regex pattern for matching URL strings that **stops** at the first comma? Trying to extract values from an array of arrays in Google Sheets.

**Cell A1**

```
{https://www.myshop.com/shop/the_first_shop,Marcus. White's. Shop.,ACTIVE,US};{https://www.myshop.com/shop/a-second-shop,The first! Shop,CLOSED,UK};{EMPTY,ClosedShop,CLOSED,IN}
```

**Desired Output (Cell B1)**

```
https://www.myshop.com/shop/the_first_shop,https://www.myshop.com/shop/a-second-shop
```

I have figured out how to get a clean array of matching values in my desired output cell using:

```
=trim(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"/(https?:\/\/[^ ]*)/"," "),";"," "),"}"," "),"{"," "))
```

But I can't find a regex pattern that stops at a comma. For example, this soution:

```
"/(https?:\/\/[^ ]*)/"
```

matches the first URL, but gives me back:

```
https://www.myshop.com/shop/the_first_shop,Marcus. White's. Shop.,ACTIVE,US https://www.myshop.com/shop/a-second-shop,The first! Shop,CLOSED,UK EMPTY,ClosedShop,CLOSED,IN
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with `REGEXREPLACE` and use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,".*?(?:(https.*?)|$)","$1")
```

Just a trailing comma to deal with...

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,".*?(?:(https.*?(,))|$)","$1"),",$","")
```

A much longer alternative to `REGEXREPLACE` could be:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"{","}"),"}",","),",")),"Select Col1 where Col1 like 'http%'"))
```

Comment: This returned all of the URL matches (not just the first) perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> regex pattern that stops at a comma

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(https?:\/\/[^,]*)")
```

[image]